# Grails ehcache plugin cache not expiring

Tags: caching, grails, configuration, ehcache

With the Grails [ehcache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-ehcache) I'm trying to cache a response and occasionally refresh that response.

This is what I have in my Config.groovy,

```
grails.cache.config = {
    cache {
        name 'winners'
        eternal false
        timeToLiveSeconds 10
    }
}
```

And I annotating the winners endpoint with `@Cacheable('winners')`.

**I am seeing the response get cached, but I am never seeing the cache expire.** Anyone have any clue what might be going on here?

Comment: This may be broken, http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHEEHCACHE-4?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel, the ticket description isn't vey clear to me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Adding `ehcache.xml` file into the config directory seemed to fix it.

See http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/grails for details.

Btw, I had to replace the attributes '`maxEntriesLocalHeap`' with '`maxElementsInMemory`'.

Comment: I've honestly moved on from my initial question at this point and I am not in a position to test your answer. At some point I may revisit Grails caching, but until then accept an upvote for being the only one to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is caused by a bug related to the Grails cache plugin not respecting the TTL settings for EhCache (applies only for Controller action responses). I was not able to work around this bug and had to create a separate Quartz job for periodically flushing the cache.